# Understanding the Lebesgue measure, and $m(\{x\}) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My professor is using Folland's Real Analysis, and the question is to show that $m((a , b)) = b - a$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $L$ is the Lebesgue measurable sets.

My attempt at a solution really hinges on my understanding of things. We have defined our elementary family $E$ as the set of all $(a,b]$ where a,b are between negative and positive infinity. From this, with the standard construction of the Lebesgue measure, can I assume that $m((a,b]) = b-a$?

Now, let us begin with my attempt at the proof:

First, let us show that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $m(\{ x \})=0$:

First, note that $\{x\}$ is Lebesgue measurable, since $ \forall A \subset R$:

$$
\begin{align}
m(A) = m(A \cap \{x \}) + m(A \cap \{x \}^{c})\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$

If $A \cap \{x\}$ is empty, this is clear, but if $A \cap \{x\}$ is non-empty, then

$m(A \cap \{x\}) + m(A \cap \{x \}^{c}) = m(\{x \}) + m(A \cap \{x\}^{c}) = m(\{x\} \cup A \cap \{x \}^{c}) = m(A)$.
(Not too sure about this line. The second to last equality I am using properties of outer measure, but can I do that?)

Thus $\{x \}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Then since $\forall E \in L$ we have that $m(E) = \inf\left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty m((a_{j},b_{j}]) : E \subseteq \cup_{j=1}^\infty (a_{j}, b_{j}]  \right)$ and noting that for $\epsilon > 0$:

$$\{ x \} \subset \left(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{j}}, x+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{j}} \right] $$ (Edit: I placed a right parenthesis here when I meant a bracket. It was late last night when I typed this up.)

we can apply the infimum property above to find that $m(\{x\}) \leq 2\epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon$ go to zero, we have that $m(\{x\}) = 0$.

From this, and noting that $(a,b) \cup \{b\} = (a,b]$, we can show that $m((a,b)) = b - a$.

My biggest concern is with how I show that the singleton is Lebesgue measurable, and if I can even use that $m((a,b]) = b - a $. I really don't see why not, but this is a very difficult class to understand. I see that the premeasure of $(a,b]$ is $b - a$, and then I see that the outer measure is equal to the premeasure for $(a,b]$ since it is in our algebra, and I think this means that this is the Lebesgue measure of it as well. But again, I really want to make sure I am getting this.

Comment: Since your elementary sets are of the form $(a,b]$, then all your work assumes that $m((a,b]) = b-a$. So you can use that.

Comment: @etfhan: I edited your question for clarity. The measurability of $\{x\}$ follows from equation (1), which says that $\{x\}$ satisfies the Caratheodory measurability condition. That is how measurable sets are defined in many texts (including Folland's)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Try find a cover for the singleton in terms of half-closed intervals as you mentioned, so that it belongs to the semiring $\mathcal{S}$ you defined. Then you can use monotonicity of outer measures you defined. And I think you have some problems in defining the outer measure you've just indicated.

Comment: I made a typo, so now it should be better. What are the problems with the outer measure? And what about showing that {x} is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late. Your definition of outer measure now seems fine to me. I think others have edited your question by showing that the singleton is Lebesgue measurable.